# Instead of h-full is there a function to make it h- section full

Tags: html, vue.js, tailwind-css

I am trying to write a scroll element that bounces using the tailwind animate capability. However the bounce size it too big as I have set the container to `h-full`. Is there a way of having the container span the size of the `<section>` instead of the entire page? Or be able to limit the size of the container in a way that is reactive.

ps. I am using the container function to help align the flex to the center of the page

```
  <div class="container h-screen animate-bounce w-screen flex justify-center object-center">
    <div class="scroll flex-column absolute z-10 object-center">
      <h2 class="text-yellow-500 text-xs uppercase m-auto">scroll</h2>
      <img src="~/static/group-3.png" class="Scroll-Arrow m-auto">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: on which element do you want this height?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim the container element

Comment: your issue is not clear

Answer (score 0):

try like this sample,

```
<div class="container h-40 mt-10 animate-bounce w-screen flex justify-center object-center"> <--first div
  <div class="scroll flex-col absolute z-10 object-center"> <--second div
    <h2 class="text-yellow-500 text-xs uppercase m-auto">scroll</h2>
    <img src="~/static/group-3.png" class="h-20 scroll-arrow m-auto" />
  </div>
</div>
```

`Container` just define `width` and `max-width` not about `height`

You can adjust with your target `height` values with giving `h-x` values.

happy coding ;)